# SyntaxError in StaticPagesController#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

After attempting to load the home page, or any page for that matter, in my sample app, I receive the following error:

**C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...ate_attribute (:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token)) ... ^ C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end**

here's my sessions_helper code:

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute (:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space after the method name:

```
user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
```